# How to get a vector of sums from a sequence of cell arrays elements?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 2 vectors of length n, the first one is composed by integers and the second one by reals between 0 and 1. Es:

```
 a = [6 2 5 3] and b = [0.1 0.2 0.04 1]
```

I needed at first to replicate the values of the second vector a as many times as the number of the first vector a (row-wise): for example for the first element I need 6 rows with value 0.1, than for the second one 2 other rows with values 0.2 and so on filling an all vector. The resulting vectors would look like this:

B= [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 1 1 1 ]

I used repmat in a for loop (for each row) to obtain this result. The problem is that the vector will soon become too large and it gets quickly stuck since I am working with large numbers. So, I have tried to store each new 'repmat vector' in a matrix with predetermined number of rows r (which I need to have r relatively high) and use vec2mat with pad=NaN to adjust for the dimension. This works well but still the matrix to fill is of size to high and at a given point the loop gets stuck. I have also tried to store each new 'repmat vector' in array. This works well and really quickly and the final result is an array with n cells, with each cell containing the vectors of different length. In the example above I will obtain a array c 1x4 with in the first cell there is the vector [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1], in the second one there is the vector  [0.2 0.2] and so on.

At this stage there is my problem. Fixing an integer r, I need to compute a sequence of sums, summing values (each r elements) of all values in the cells taken sequentially. This means, I need to take the first r values of the first cell, than continue with the sum of the second set of r values right after the first set. When the vector of the first cell is finished it should start of the the second cell and so till the last cell of the array. The problem is that r could be higher or lower than the length of different vectors in each cell of the array. Than it can happen that for example in computing the second sum the values needed are the last rows of the vector in the first cell and the first rows of the vector in the second cell. However, I do not get to have access on elements of different cell sequentially.

In the example above, fixing a value of r=4, the result would be a vector of 3 x 1 :

res = [sum1 sum2 sum3]  where

sum1 is computed taking the first r=5 rows of the vector of the first cells -->(0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1);

sum2 is computed taking the next r=5 elements, i.e. the last rows of the vector in the first cell, the two rows of the vector in the second cell and the first two rows of the vector in the third cell -->(0.1+0.2+0.2+0.04+0.04);

sum3 is computed taking the next r=5 elements, i.e. the last three rows of the vector in the third cell and the two first rows of the vector in the fourth cell and the first two rows of the vector in the third cell -->(0.04+0.04+0.04+1+1);

Then there is the last row of the vector of the last cell which value is 1 that it is not used and can be delated.

I actually do not need all the intermediate steps but only the final vector res with all the sums. However, I do not get how to go from the vectors a and b to the vector of res without go throughout this steps which in the case of 'matrix building' I got stuck and kind of 'out of memory' problems and in the case of cells array I did not get to access values in different cells sequentially. Is there a way to get a solution ?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

John

Answer (score 2):

Variant of Notlikethat's answer, which uses multiplication instead of addition. This might be slightly faster on really big inputs, especially when `r` and the average number of repetitions (values in `a`) are large:

```
a = [6 2 5 3];
b = [0.1 0.2 0.04 1];
r = 5;

nres = floor(sum(a) / r);
result = zeros(1, nres); % preallocate
isrc = 1;

for idest = 1:nres
    n_todo = r;
    while n_todo > 0
        n_possible = min(n_todo, a(isrc));
        result(idest) = result(idest) + n_possible * b(isrc);
        n_todo = n_todo - n_possible;
        a(isrc) = a(isrc) - n_possible;
        if a(isrc) <= 0
            isrc = isrc + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Note that it modifies `a`, so make a copy if you still need it. Result:

```
result =

    0.5000    0.5800    2.1200
```

Comment: This variant is amazingly faster. Thank you

Comment: Since vector a and b where time series, for each value in the vectors there were attached a date/Time in the number format like 

41603,3777777778 --> 6
41603,3784722222 --> 2
41603,3791666667 --> 5
41603,3798611111 --> 3

There is a way to obtain the interval (start and end date/Time) within each sum in result are computed?

Comment: I have tried to register the position in the vector 'a' by putting after the first end : ind(idest,1)=isrc; then I can retrieve the same position in the vector of Date/Time. It seems working but I am not sure that the position are right. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is Matlab and everyone hates loops, but if your data is big then avoiding making copies of it is even more important. The C programmer in me says can do the whole process without making any intermediate copies at all:

```
a = [6 2 5 3];
b = [0.1 0.2 0.04 1];
r = 5;

res = zeros(1, floor(sum(a)/r));
srcidx = 1;
srccount = 1;
for destidx = 1:numel(res)
    for sumcount = 1:r
        if srccount > a(srcidx)
            srcidx = srcidx + 1;
            srccount = 1;
        end
        res(destidx) = res(destidx) + b(srcidx);
        srccount = srccount + 1;
    end
end
```

Besides, slow code that works is still better than fast code that doesn't ;)

```
>> res
res =

   0.50000   0.58000   2.12000
```

Comment: That is the key, not storing the copies of intermediate steps allows to save way much time. Thank you for the great advice. For info, I encountered a small error in the computation of the last sum. A difference of order 10^-5.

Comment: @user3395736 Indeed - this method works if the input range is small enough, but falls apart if it's large since you can't sort the input values to minimise loss of precision when accumulating. Bas' multiplication-based version is probably somewhat more robust against that.